# Название компонента в приложении Google Задачи

Tags: android, material-design

Не могу найти компонент который используется в приложении "Задачи" от Google, нужна панель которая сворачивается при нажатии на иконку аккаунта или стрелку. Я думаю что это новый компонент, подскажите где искать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вот вам статейка как сделать точно такую же с закругленными углами https://medium.com/halcyon-mobile/implementing-googles-refreshed-modal-bottom-sheet-4e76cb5de65b

Comment: Благодарю! Это что нужно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это Bottom Sheet. Поведение настраивается через `BottomSheetBehavior`. 
В нужном `layout` укажите что у вас должно выезжать и свяжите эту вью с `BottomSheetBehavior`. Соответственно на нужную вью можно повесить клики и по кликам закрывать или открывать панельку через метод `setState`